# How to write a fraction in Microsoft Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

How to write a fraction in Excel.  I want to write it exactly as shown in the picture.

Is what I want possible?

[image]

Comment: Did you try format number fraction?

Comment: exactly means with the proper horizontal line? If yes, then answer is no, you can't get it in a cell, but you can get it in an equation (insert tab - equation)

Comment: I removed the [equation-editor] tag since the OP did not specify they were using it, nor ask for assistance with it. Adding it changes the OP's question to what we think they want. Let the OP clarify.

Comment: Do you want to use the fraction in any calculations too? Or just want to display the fraction in a cell/image/whatever?

Comment: This may be of interest: [Styled Fractions in Windows](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/wiki/msoffice_word-mso_other/styled-fractions-in-windows/4a07d5fa-2484-4e39-b1f3-70bb3eb0c332)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

- In Excel go to `Insert → Object`.
- From the list select "Microsoft Equation 3.0".
- Select the equation that suits your needs. In this case:

[image]

- Type **2**, press TAB key to move the cursor and then **3**.

---

This is my result:

[image]

Comment: since office 2010 (or 2007, not sure because it was too long since the last time I used them) you don't use MS equation anymore. Equation tool is embedded into all applications (unlike MS equation which is an optional part)

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc in all office 365 apps, the insert -> equation is present next to the insert -> symbols.

Comment: @Tim That's exactly what I mean. I've never seen office 365 but I think it's similar to other offline offices. Probably you haven't used office 97 or 2000? They don't have equation feature included but you must install a separate Microsoft equation. This answer is about insert > objects > MS equation 3.0, not about insert > equation

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc I used 97 a while back, but I'm not even sure it was called excel then? Office 365 is office 2016, pretty similar to 2013 features.

Comment: @Tim it has always been named Excel since version 2.0 in 1987. I still remember Excel 97 even has a hidden racing game in it.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: Actually, since Excel version 1.0 in 1985.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition This is getting off-topic for this comment thread; perhaps interested persons could ask on [retrocomputing.se].

Comment: To future readers: **Do not ever use this way** and use the new built-in equation feature instead. TBH this doesn't deserve so many upvotes. [Pokechu22's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1191251/241386) is the correct way to do in all modern versions of Excel and should be accepted instead

Answer (score 19):

Inside of a text box (Insert→Text Box), but *not* inside of a cell unfortunately, you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> (or "New Equation" on the insert tab).  This lets you freely type an equation (or use the ribbon's editor); typing `x/y` will automatically reformat it to a fraction, or you can manually insert a fraction and type into it.

[image: Equation editor]

[image: Equation in a text box]

I recommend this over Insert→Object because this type of equation uses a newer, cleaner editor (and you don't need to wait for the objects list to load).  Neither option can be used within a cell, so this one is preferable.

Comment: you can type things like `(x+y)/3<space>` and it'll convert to the fraction for you automatically, without the parentheses

Answer (score 18):

If you don't want to mess with the equation editor, and all you are looking to do is display the fraction, you can simply use regular cells with a border between the upper and lower cell. Then resize the cells to format it the way you like.

[image]

Comment: Also you could (using the image here as an example) merge cells C2 and C3 then vertically center the text in the merged cell, to have your text line up with the fraction line.

Answer (score 9):

A third possibility: common fractions such as ⅓(1/3), ⅔(2/3), ¾(3/4), ⅝(5/8).. have Unicode representations, see http://unicodefractions.com/ . If it's these you need, rather than arbitrary representations with any numerator and denominator, the answer may lie with substring and string concatenation functions to generate the label or formatting you want.

Comment: Can you elaborate how to use this in Excel?

Comment: Sorry, no. I could tell you how to use it in LibreOffice, but I'm at a rare Linux-only workplace!

Comment: For the purpose of improving clarity of your answer, can you at some point elaborate? The idea here is to answer the question related to what the OP has asked it (in this case Excel). To do so sometimes requires us to provide instructions how to implement suggested answer.

Comment: Libreoffice: this expression `=CONCATENATE("abc  ",MID(A1,B1,1))` joins "abc " with the (unicode) character at offset calculated in cell B1 from cell A1. For example if A1 contained space 1/8 1/4 3/8 ... (SO won't display unicodes in comments!) and B1 was =INT((D1 - INT(D1))*8)+1, you'd get the fractional part of D1 rounded down to eightths as a fraction.

Comment: To enter unicodes (again Libreoffice but probably general) you do ctrl/shift/u followed by the hex digits of the unicode in question.

Comment: In Excel (Windows), go to ribbon Insert > Symbol > Subset "Number Forms" or scroll down > Select from ⅓ to ⅞. See [support.office.com](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Insert-a-symbol-fraction-or-special-character-57c021a0-86e7-4332-a319-8eb3c5dfcb35). Note that these do not look *exactly* as the OP requested.

Comment: Also if you're on windows, [start -> run -> charmap then search for "fraction"](https://i.snag.gy/EIvL8o.jpg). Available choices will depend on selected font.

Answer (score 8):

Another possibility is to use [Unicode subscripts and superscripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts) if you want arbitrary values, not only common fractions like ⅔, ¼, ⅝...

The numerator can be written using the superscript numbers `⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹` and the denominator can be written with subscript numbers `₀₁₂₃₄₅₆₇₈₉`. The delimiter between them can be solidus `/` or fraction slash `⁄` depending on your taste

For example ⁴⁵/₈₉, ⁷⁄₂₃

As you can see the fraction slash has the advantage of better kerning/ligature/font substitution support and the numbers really overlap each other

---

If you want to show a vertical fraction then simply use the horizontal [box-drawing characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character) `─` for the horizontal line. This way the line is always in the exact middle of the 2 numbers and multiple lines connect to each other continuously instead of a dashed line

```
 123
─────
45678
```

Comment: Good, also great for encouraging people to update their software when it throws small boxes of nonsense all around their screen :)

Answer (score 7):

The OP hasn't indicated if there is any need to actually use the fraction in the spreadsheet, or if it is simply a need to display a fraction.

### Display and not use as a value

If you want to simply make a cell display a fraction

[image]

Then type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> followed by 153 followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> followed by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> followed by 71

Although this will display as a fraction, the cell value will be the string 15371, so not suitable for a formula where you want the actual value of the fraction.

### Display fraction and use as a value

You can get Excel to display a value as a fraction, however the format does not show a horizontal line, but rather uses 153/71

To get Excel to show a number as a fraction, format the cell to have a custom number format as follows:

```
0/###
```

Be aware that the number of # symbols will limit the magnitude of the denominator. If you set the format to be 0/# then 153/71 will *display* rounded to 13/6 however the actual cell value accuracy will remain and the cell can be referred to in a formula.

Comment: If you want to use codes for the special characters, then, (for codes up to 254), you can enter them into Excel (Windows) by holding down the [ALT] key and typing the code preceded by 0.  
eg [ALT] + 0190  will type in  ¾   **Note: this will not provide a fraction useful for an equation!)**

Comment: using underline formatting results in an ugly output like above. The horizontal box-drawing character `─` works much better. Also you should use it with center alignment

Answer (score 2):

In Excel 2007 and later, you can insert an equation by clicking on Equation in the Insert tab:

[image]

When you've done that, you will get a place to type an equation. You can either use the "Fraction" button in the "Equation tools" tab (which shows up automatically when you insert an equation, or if you type a fraction of the type `2/3` and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> it will automatically convert to a fraction. This is the result I got:

[image]

The equation can be moved around like an image so you can put it where you want.

If you're using an older version than Excel 2007, [User552853's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1191175/513819) explains how to do this in older versions of Excel.

Comment: isn't this already answered by [Pokechu22](https://superuser.com/a/1191251/241386) above?

Answer (score 1):

If you're okay with your fractions not using ***strictly*** a horizontal line (OP was asked but never replied), this is how you enter fractions to be used as values within a cell in Excel:

`WholeNumber`<kbd>spacebar</kbd>`Numerator`<kbd>/</kbd>`Denominator`<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

So if you wanted to enter 1/12th, you'd do,

`0 1/12` and in excel it would display as:

> 1/12

And the value would be available for computation as `0.0833333333333333`

For one more example, if your fraction was 2 and 7/38ths, you'd enter it as `2 7/38`

I added some visuals below in case that helps more.

[image]

That should give you this result:

[image]

Comment: "I want to write it exactly as shown in the picture."

Comment: The OP never answered _your_ own question to clarify if it needed to be the horizontal line. This answer will help people that want to know how to enter fractions displayed as fractions and still usable in excel, so I'm keeping it here.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a Macro to do that:

```vb
Sub Fraction()
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Range("b3") & Chr(10) & "—" & Chr(10) & Range("c3")
        With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With    
End Sub
```

This is the result I got:

[image: Result]

Comment: Just wanna remind you to post your result.

Comment: you use only one "—", so how about wider fractions like 23/45 or 145/236?

Comment: besides, it's better to use the horizontal box-drawing character ─ instead of the em-dash

Answer (score -2):

You need to use the ALT button. I use it constantly in my workbooks, but it is limited to the basic fractions, although you can do much more with it too. Once you get the hang of it, it becomes second nature and it looks much more professional. 
So 1/4 = Alt + 0188 (while holding down the alt button) | 1/2 = ALT + 0189 | 3/4 = ALT + 0190. 
The end result looks like this 1¾, not 13/4.
Check this site https://usefulshortcuts.com/downloads/ALT-Codes.pdf
Hope this helps as much as it helped me. I spent a long time struggling with this same problem.

Comment: Your answer is substantially the same as this existing answer: https://superuser.com/a/1191216/427317